# ScrollTop/ScrollBottom Issues in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to test out a function in jquery where I have a vertical progress bar next to some text. The ideal function is that the value of the progress bar fills as the user scrolls down. I've got it to work perfectly except that the progress bar fills from the bottom to the top. I want it to fill from the top to the bottom, so the color drips down the progress bar.

[image]

Can someone help? Here's my code.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var s = $(window).scrollTop(),
    d = $(document).height(),
    c = $(window).height();
  scrollPercent = (s / (d - c)) * 100;
  var position = scrollPercent;

  $("#progressbar").attr('value', position);

});
```

```css
progress {
  position: fixed;
  top: 15px;
}

.vertical {
  margin-top: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
  height: 40px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container mt-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-2">
      <progress class="vertical" id="progressbar" value="0" max="100"></progress>
    </div>
    <div class="col-10">
      <p class="card-text">
        Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga obcaecati iusto, commodi hic doloremque cumque consequatur! Iste, quaerat. Officiis voluptas modi cupiditate similique quos obcaecati exercitationem saepe. Neque, molestias voluptatum. Nobis
        illo commodi temporibus hic soluta quas odit aperiam dicta mollitia? Dolor neque similique delectus tenetur, officiis id consequatur molestias quaerat! Iste aspernatur laborum animi rem molestiae possimus eligendi laudantium! Tempore asperiores
        repellendus dolore corrupti, deleniti, aperiam culpa vitae repellat, hic quaerat cum facilis laborum! Dignissimos sapiente temporibus quas beatae natus placeat error dolor, praesentium assumenda voluptatum adipisci blanditiis reprehenderit. Pariatur
        ipsum eum molestiae non. Nisi a id voluptas? Iste, ad cum autem amet magni aut quidem neque laboriosam, cumque quaerat itaque necessitatibus velit dolores architecto optio reiciendis pariatur animi. Doloremque nemo quia cupiditate asperiores obcaecati,
        nobis iure labore in deleniti perspiciatis necessitatibus accusamus ad cum provident libero. Repellendus et suscipit quaerat pariatur sed corporis dolores laborum voluptate odit ullam! Cum, quis voluptatum obcaecati quibusdam illum dolores dolor
        nihil velit, officia nisi, harum est perferendis impedit laudantium optio. Hic ipsam dolorem eos sit assumenda veritatis quia quis accusamus molestiae soluta? Deserunt, beatae placeat! Quidem porro ipsam aspernatur facere tempore incidunt nisi
        consequatur veritatis, tempora laborum a est asperiores adipisci. Asperiores eius sapiente quisquam, vero voluptatibus quae fugiat dicta maxime natus. Excepturi commodi quidem magnam ullam repudiandae, sapiente nesciunt iste veritatis iure ea
        velit facere pariatur voluptas tempora assumenda! Magni provident voluptates quam voluptatem vel fugit illum eius nam praesentium accusamus! Suscipit reiciendis atque magnam. Laudantium exercitationem suscipit facilis nemo tempora consectetur
        facere ipsam quo, incidunt voluptatibus est earum atque culpa nobis modi voluptatum vero nulla sed impedit error! Cum, dolores! Molestias vitae velit, nam amet magni eveniet et minus odio accusamus nulla nisi vel unde similique voluptatem consectetur
        laborum enim magnam mollitia aspernatur? Ab eligendi soluta accusantium, laboriosam numquam nam?
      </p>
      <p class="card-text">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro velit, ullam sequi expedita neque tenetur aspernatur quisquam explicabo placeat, facilis eos inventore mollitia in iure dicta id sint hic perferendis. Reprehenderit fugit distinctio consequatur
        quibusdam. Rerum perspiciatis natus ad, necessitatibus beatae minus nemo molestias sit, corporis quo dolor magnam sed totam dicta eveniet aperiam quia voluptas labore voluptatem quibusdam soluta? Porro dicta distinctio odio maxime tempora! Illum
        repudiandae, quod eum obcaecati quae voluptates tempore ea ullam, earum assumenda, rem veniam amet beatae ratione magnam fugiat sapiente asperiores recusandae facere quos. Enim, est dolorum! Repellat perspiciatis explicabo ducimus quo iste vel,
        deserunt quia eaque, dignissimos corrupti, in non eveniet minima voluptates delectus temporibus rem libero ad excepturi sunt accusamus unde ipsam. Laboriosam blanditiis dolor voluptatum tenetur. Quae maiores dignissimos molestias dolore beatae
        fugiat veniam mollitia eius illo enim nesciunt est qui possimus cupiditate laboriosam, rerum minima. Sequi dolorem eius aliquam quia. Magnam eos quas molestiae unde beatae consequuntur maiores itaque aperiam, totam labore quidem dicta sunt pariatur
        inventore recusandae ea! Eius eaque molestiae sunt, hic sed possimus? Tenetur commodi laborum necessitatibus. Unde debitis harum facere ab at! Quod accusantium explicabo, atque laboriosam rerum voluptatum. Tempore iusto distinctio hic est a, mollitia
        ad explicabo. Veritatis, commodi! Corporis sint provident natus impedit nihil! Porro labore voluptates veniam ducimus! Culpa sint eos distinctio itaque tenetur esse expedita libero at dolorem assumenda vero molestiae repellat, provident laboriosam
        tempore, earum placeat perferendis consequatur praesentium. Repellendus, laboriosam? Repellat, expedita sequi. Doloribus quod, magnam consequatur, numquam vel omnis iure doloremque obcaecati deleniti ullam adipisci perspiciatis aliquam, ratione
        distinctio non expedita aperiam? A, saepe! Itaque nam at recusandae doloremque? Ipsa et aut dicta, obcaecati eligendi, tempore soluta aspernatur culpa hic sed, rem a voluptatum assumenda unde illum perspiciatis velit reprehenderit ratione distinctio
        mollitia. Eligendi, assumenda iusto. Reiciendis, accusamus quam.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You want the sky blue bar show from top to bottom when scrolling? Simply just change on css
 -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: rotate(90deg);

Comment: yes, exactly. Right now, as I scroll down, the progress bar fills from the bottom to the top. I want it to fill from the top to the bottom as I scroll down.

Comment: Simply change on css vertical class

 -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: rotate(90deg);

Comment: Do you want the progress bar to be at 100% at the beginning and the go to 0 as you scrool down?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **`transform: rotate(90deg)`** instead of **`transform: rotate(-90deg)`**

**`rotate(-90deg)`** rotate your progress bar into anti-clockwise

0 to 180 is clockwise, 0 to -180 is counterclockwise. So, positive number rotates clockwise, negative - other way around.

> ***[More help on rotate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/rotate)***

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var s = $(window).scrollTop(),
    d = $(document).height(),
    c = $(window).height();
  scrollPercent = (s / (d - c)) * 100;
  var position = scrollPercent;

  $("#progressbar").attr('value', position);

});
```

```css
progress {
  position: fixed;
  top: 15px;
}

.vertical {
  margin-top: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
  height: 40px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container mt-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-2">
      <progress class="vertical" id="progressbar" value="0" max="100"></progress>
    </div>
    <div class="col-10">
      <p class="card-text">
        Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga obcaecati iusto, commodi hic doloremque cumque consequatur! Iste, quaerat. Officiis voluptas modi cupiditate similique quos obcaecati exercitationem saepe. Neque, molestias voluptatum. Nobis
        illo commodi temporibus hic soluta quas odit aperiam dicta mollitia? Dolor neque similique delectus tenetur, officiis id consequatur molestias quaerat! Iste aspernatur laborum animi rem molestiae possimus eligendi laudantium! Tempore asperiores
        repellendus dolore corrupti, deleniti, aperiam culpa vitae repellat, hic quaerat cum facilis laborum! Dignissimos sapiente temporibus quas beatae natus placeat error dolor, praesentium assumenda voluptatum adipisci blanditiis reprehenderit. Pariatur
        ipsum eum molestiae non. Nisi a id voluptas? Iste, ad cum autem amet magni aut quidem neque laboriosam, cumque quaerat itaque necessitatibus velit dolores architecto optio reiciendis pariatur animi. Doloremque nemo quia cupiditate asperiores obcaecati,
        nobis iure labore in deleniti perspiciatis necessitatibus accusamus ad cum provident libero. Repellendus et suscipit quaerat pariatur sed corporis dolores laborum voluptate odit ullam! Cum, quis voluptatum obcaecati quibusdam illum dolores dolor
        nihil velit, officia nisi, harum est perferendis impedit laudantium optio. Hic ipsam dolorem eos sit assumenda veritatis quia quis accusamus molestiae soluta? Deserunt, beatae placeat! Quidem porro ipsam aspernatur facere tempore incidunt nisi
        consequatur veritatis, tempora laborum a est asperiores adipisci. Asperiores eius sapiente quisquam, vero voluptatibus quae fugiat dicta maxime natus. Excepturi commodi quidem magnam ullam repudiandae, sapiente nesciunt iste veritatis iure ea
        velit facere pariatur voluptas tempora assumenda! Magni provident voluptates quam voluptatem vel fugit illum eius nam praesentium accusamus! Suscipit reiciendis atque magnam. Laudantium exercitationem suscipit facilis nemo tempora consectetur
        facere ipsam quo, incidunt voluptatibus est earum atque culpa nobis modi voluptatum vero nulla sed impedit error! Cum, dolores! Molestias vitae velit, nam amet magni eveniet et minus odio accusamus nulla nisi vel unde similique voluptatem consectetur
        laborum enim magnam mollitia aspernatur? Ab eligendi soluta accusantium, laboriosam numquam nam?
      </p>
      <p class="card-text">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro velit, ullam sequi expedita neque tenetur aspernatur quisquam explicabo placeat, facilis eos inventore mollitia in iure dicta id sint hic perferendis. Reprehenderit fugit distinctio consequatur
        quibusdam. Rerum perspiciatis natus ad, necessitatibus beatae minus nemo molestias sit, corporis quo dolor magnam sed totam dicta eveniet aperiam quia voluptas labore voluptatem quibusdam soluta? Porro dicta distinctio odio maxime tempora! Illum
        repudiandae, quod eum obcaecati quae voluptates tempore ea ullam, earum assumenda, rem veniam amet beatae ratione magnam fugiat sapiente asperiores recusandae facere quos. Enim, est dolorum! Repellat perspiciatis explicabo ducimus quo iste vel,
        deserunt quia eaque, dignissimos corrupti, in non eveniet minima voluptates delectus temporibus rem libero ad excepturi sunt accusamus unde ipsam. Laboriosam blanditiis dolor voluptatum tenetur. Quae maiores dignissimos molestias dolore beatae
        fugiat veniam mollitia eius illo enim nesciunt est qui possimus cupiditate laboriosam, rerum minima. Sequi dolorem eius aliquam quia. Magnam eos quas molestiae unde beatae consequuntur maiores itaque aperiam, totam labore quidem dicta sunt pariatur
        inventore recusandae ea! Eius eaque molestiae sunt, hic sed possimus? Tenetur commodi laborum necessitatibus. Unde debitis harum facere ab at! Quod accusantium explicabo, atque laboriosam rerum voluptatum. Tempore iusto distinctio hic est a, mollitia
        ad explicabo. Veritatis, commodi! Corporis sint provident natus impedit nihil! Porro labore voluptates veniam ducimus! Culpa sint eos distinctio itaque tenetur esse expedita libero at dolorem assumenda vero molestiae repellat, provident laboriosam
        tempore, earum placeat perferendis consequatur praesentium. Repellendus, laboriosam? Repellat, expedita sequi. Doloribus quod, magnam consequatur, numquam vel omnis iure doloremque obcaecati deleniti ullam adipisci perspiciatis aliquam, ratione
        distinctio non expedita aperiam? A, saepe! Itaque nam at recusandae doloremque? Ipsa et aut dicta, obcaecati eligendi, tempore soluta aspernatur culpa hic sed, rem a voluptatum assumenda unde illum perspiciatis velit reprehenderit ratione distinctio
        mollitia. Eligendi, assumenda iusto. Reiciendis, accusamus quam.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand your answer. I already have it rotated 90degress in the CSS.

Comment: @J.G.Sable you rotated it in anti-clockwise direction. Try to rotate it clockwise. See updated answer

Comment: Perfect. Thanks! Works great now.

Comment: @J.G.Sable Glad to help:)